fried e-bike controller. replaced with stock part but still doesn't work
I fried my e- bike controller (jasion) but when I replaced it my bike still doesn't work. I have double checked all the connections and think that maybe the display is the problem. HELP!

Much more detail would really be necessary to say anything specific. What actually happened? What does "still doesn't work" actually mean? What kind of bike it is? What specific type of controller? How exactly is it connected to which exact parts?

Take your time and check all connectors to insure they are fully pressed in and seated. Unplug then plug back in all connectors and inspect pins inside connectors. Check for broken pins, corroded pins and pins that aren't making contact. After inspecting or repairing connections, check to see if turns on. If it turns on then you'll need to set the parameters correctly. If it wont turn on then you can try using a multimeter to find where the power drops off at and do the repair and if still cant get it to work then might be best for you to bring it to a repair shop. Give it 110% before doing that though. You can do this.

Hmmm - Stop and figure out how the previous damage occurred.  Fix the cause or prevent it from happening again.
Then start replacing components that don't work any more.   You may have taken the display along with the controller during the initial damage.
Good luck !
